# How to stop a call resulting in IAsyncOperation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, bluetooth-lowenergy, iasyncoperation

In my application I notify multiple devices. If a device is not reachable and is not responding within a few seconds, i want to cancel the call.

My code is:
`await characteristic0.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync
(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);`

Now after some research i found out that usually one can pass a **CancelationToken** (_ct) and do this:

First create an operation containing the call:
`IAsyncOperation<GattCommunicationStatus> operation = characteristic0.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync
(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);`

Then creating a task with a CancellationToken:
`Task<GattCommunicationStatus> task = operation.AsTask(_ct);`

And then await it:
`GattCommunicationStatus status = await task;`

Now, the thing is even though the **IsCancellationRequested**-Property of the **CancellationToken** is set to true. The call wont stop.
And, the Device is getting **Notified** after the first line already! Isn't that supposed to happen after the call to `await`??

Do i make a mistake with the Token or is this a bigger thing?

**EDIT**
After the conversation with @Andrii Litvinov i put some more code to my initial description of the problem. Here is the whole method:

```
public async Task<GattCommunicationStatus> NotifyDevice(DeviceInformationDisplay deviceInfo, CancellationToken _ct)
        {
            try
            {
                BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
                service = device.GetGattService(new Guid(Service_UUID));
                characteristic0 = service.GetCharacteristics(new Guid(Characteristic_0_UUID)).First();

                characteristic0.ValueChanged += characteristic0ValueChanged;
                GattCommunicationStatus status = await characteristic0.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
                _ct.Register(() =>
                {
                // trying to cancel the operation somehow
                });
                IAsyncOperation<GattCommunicationStatus> operation = characteristic0.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
                Task<GattCommunicationStatus> task = operation.AsTask(_ct);
                GattCommunicationStatus status_1 = await task;

                if (!elapsedTimeWatcher.IsRunning)
                {
                    elapsedTimeWatcher.Start();
                }

                else
                {
                    elapsedTimeWatcher.Restart();
                }
                return status;
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException e)
            {
                return GattCommunicationStatus.Unreachable;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return GattCommunicationStatus.Unreachable;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Cancellation is *cooperative*. The operation to be cancelled needs to *know about* a cancellation token and *observe* the request for cancellation. If a long-running operation doesn't have an overload that *accepts* a cancellation token, just having one in its vicinity won't do anything.

Comment: So you're saying that if `WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync` doesnt have an overload with a CancellationToken, adding the `AsTask`, wont change anything? 
So is there no way to cancel this call?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Comment: Is there a way to kill it? In an uncooperative way?

Comment: Have you tried Close method on `operation.Close()`? Can you emulate operation that takes longer time and can be canceled? It looks like operation is already completed when you await in `await task`.

Comment: But where should i cancel the operation from? Just added some more code to the original question to show you what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779747(v=vs.110).aspx) you are doing it right:

```
try
{
...

IAsyncOperation<GattCommunicationStatus> operation =
    characteristic0.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
        GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
return await operation.AsTask(_ct);

...
}
...
```

This code should register to token and call `operation.Cancel()` behind the scene.

Can you set a token to lower value to see if operation is actually cancelled? How much time does it normally take to execute the method?

Try:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10);
await NotifyDevice(BLEDevice, cts.Token);
```

Or even lower values.

Comment: This is the weird thing!

From this line
`op = characteristic0.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);`
To this line:
`Task<GattCommunicationStatus> task = op.AsTask(cts.Token);`
Takes 7 (!!) seconds...

Comment: Okay, probably it's because operation cannot be cancelled before device reply or internal timeout occurs. I suppose after 7 seconds it will be cancelled successfully. And will work fine altogether with solution from another answer. If it blocks the UI you could consider to run it with `Task.Run`.

Comment: Yeah i guess so, i will work on the other method again and try to make the tasks work. Thx so much!

Comment: You are welcome. And if any of answers help you to solve the issue consider to accept those.